# can't access imported functions in Python

Tags: python, import, pydev, aptana

Can anyone please help me with this ?

I am moving on using PyDev Aptana for developing python codes. Here is my project structure under PyDev IDE :

```
/testProject
        /src
            /testModule  
            __init__.py
            testMod.py
        main.py
```

testMod.py file :

```
def test(n): 
    print "echo"+n
```

main.py file :

```
import testModule
testModule.test(4)
```

When I try to run this in PyDev , it gave me this error at main.py , line 2 ( where test(4) is called):

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test'
```

I change main.py to :

```
import testModule.test
testModule.test(4)
```

still gives me error `'module' object not callable!`

What is wrong with this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is basically because there is no method `test()` in `testModule`. In fact, your `testModule` is not module, but is a package, while `testMod` is a module in `testModule` package.

So, with your structure, the following will work:

```
from testModule import testMod
testMod.test(4)
```

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html for more details

Comment: I don't agree with this. A package is a package. A package is a specific directory serving as a collection of modules, which it is in this case. Probably, one may say that ``__init__`` is a module (though I wouldn't), but as of testModule - usually one won't refer to testModule as a module. See the http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages for terminology. The fact that Python treats packages as modules thanks to  ``__init__`` which content is loaded into ``testModule`` namespace, doesn't mean it is not a package, right?

Comment: This is getting to confusing...
My basic intuition is that Module is collection of function def etc. we define to use for a special project.
We define packages if we want to have different modules with same name ,so one module under different packages are not same , but  have similar name because idea of what they are doing is the same.

Answer (score 8):

You missed the `testMod` module. The full name of your method is `testModule.testMod.test`.

Comment: Specifically, `testMod` alone refers just to `__init__.py` (which can be used to provide a limited but useful subset of a whole package's API easily).